# Why do vector<int>[] and vector<vector<int>> appear to behave the same?

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

Given these two declarations:

```
vector<int> list[N];
```

and

```
vector<vector<int>> list;
```

Why does list[1].push_back(2); works in both? Theoretically First one is 1-D array like and second one is 2-D array like. (Correct me if i am wrong) ? But to my surprise i found list[1].push_back(2) working in both.

Can anyone explain how does this happen ??

Please explain, Regards and thanks

`

```
 #include <cstdio>
 #include <vector>
 using namespace std;
 int main(void) {
  vector<int>g[100100];
  int n,m,k;
  scanf("%d%d%d",&n,&m,&k);
  for(int i=0,a,b;i<m&&2==scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);++i)g[a].push_back(b),g[b].push_back(a);
  int s[100100]={0,1},v[100100]={0,1};
  for(int u=0;;++u){
    int a=s[u];
    for(int i=g[a].size();i-->0;){
      int b=g[a][i];
      if(v[b]){
        if(u-v[b]>=k){
          printf("%d\n",u-v[b]+1);
          for(int j=v[b];j<=u;++j)printf("%d ",s[j]);
          return 0;
        }
      }
      else{
        s[v[b]=u+1]=b;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`

THIS CODE IS USED TO FIND CYCLE OF LENGTH MORE THAN "K+1",a question i was working on .. you can check it out yourself with sample input and output

```
input
3 3 2
1 2
2 3
3 1
output
3
1 2 3
```

Comment: `list[1].push_back(2)` should **not** work if `list` is a `vector<int>` because `int` does not have `push_back`. Please post a complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `std::vector` is a dynamic array, **not** a linked list!

Comment: `vector<int>[]` is a helluva lot different than `vector<int>`. You might wanna change your opening statement to use `vector<int> list[N]` as the first var decl. As written, it is nonsense, and does not match the code you have.

Comment: You have an array of vectors.

Comment: yeah i got that..it is dynamically allocated array

Comment: No, it's a statically allocated array.

Comment: @nneonneo but it have resize option.. how can you resize in statically allocated array ???

Comment: `g` does not have a resize option, `g[a]` does.

Comment: My OCD got the better of me. Updated the question and opening statements to reflect the posted code. (and I hope you brought a *big* stack with that code, Holy Static, Batman!).

Comment: @WhozCraig Since he apparently doesn't know what functions are, he may get away with it (but probably just barely).  It would be an unusual problem to get a stack overflow just by calling `main`, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If works because you are declaring an *array* of vectors.

If you want to have a vector of a specific size, you need to pass the size to the constructor:

```
std::vector<int> g(size);
```

However, note that doing a `push_back` on the vector declared as above, will *increase* the size as it *adds* the value.

Comment: yes.. i got my answer i am new to vectors.. thanks for explaining that

Comment: so, vector<int>g[100100]; and vector<vector<int> >g(1001000) would be same ?

Comment: @Flawless I hope that answer included the fact that without sizing the outer vector *and* the inner vector (as opposed to just *the* vector when using a static array) that you're indexing through not one, but *two* unchecked `[]` operators.

Comment: @Flawless No. Not at all.

Comment: @WhozCraig i got your point..

Comment: @Flawless: `vector<int>g[100100]` and `vector<vector<int> >g(100100)` are somewhat similar; both will initially give you 100100 vectors of integers. In the latter case, though, you can add and remove vectors freely because you have a `vector` and not an array.

Comment: @Flawless `vector<int> g[100100];` is sort of like `vector<vector<int> > g(100100);`.  Only sort of: the first puts a lot more preasure on the stack, for example.  And probably won't do bounds checking on the index, even in debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

Both declarations are sort of similar: the first is a C style
array of vector of int, and the second is a vector of vector of
int.  When indexing, C style arrays and vectors behave
similarly: the expression `list[1].push_back(2)` uses indexing
on the outer container (C style array or vector), which works
for both.

Having said that, there *is* an important difference between the
two declarations.  The first (`vector<int> list[N]`) creates
a C style array of **N** vectors; the resulting container has
a constant size, which can never be changed.  The second
(`vector<vector<int> > list;`) creates an empty vector of
vector: there are *no* elements in `list` to begin with, and
indexing into it is undefined behavior.  On the other hand, you
can extend it dynamically as far as the memory allows.

As a general rule, you should avoid C style arrays.  Especially
as local variables, and especially if the number of elements is
fairly large.  This last is was the case even in C, since the
stack size is typically limited.

Also: whether dealing with C style arrays *or* vectors, you
should never index into them with values provided by the user
without first checking that the values are in range.  You're
code is full of undefined behavior, depending on the input.
The formatting is also pretty bad.  And using a comma operator
to put two statements in a `for` without using `{...}` is
horrible.  You should probably break this down into several
functions.  And what is the signification of the magic number
100100?  Or the fact that `s` and `v` are initialized with the
second element 1, and all of the others 0.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
vector<int> list[1];
list[0].push_back(2);
```

You are pushing back an `int(2)` into the 0th element of the array called `list`.

With

```
vector< vector<int> > list[1];
list[0].push_back(2);
```

You are pushing back a `vector<int>(2)` into the 0th element of the array called `list`.  The element you are pushing back is a vector of ints with an initial size of two.

Note: this wouldn't happen if `vector<T>(size_t)` were instead `explicit vector<T>(size_t)`.

Comment: What wouldn't happen if the constructor was `explicit`?  I don't see any implicit conversions in the above; the only use of the `size_t` constructor is direct initialization, which works with an `explicit` constructor as well.

Comment: @JamesKanze Hey, I remember you from usenet news! Anyway, in the second example, 2 is implicitly converted to vector<int>(2).  Also, I got my explicit in the wrong place.  I know the question is closed, but let me fix that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` has a constructor which takes a single size argument and default constructs that many objects into it.

With C++ 11 this constructor is explicit, but I'm guessing you are compiling in C++ 98 mode, in which case pushing `1` into the `vector<vector<int> >list` will cause the `1` to be implicitly converted to `vector<int>(1)`.

Comment: I kind of assumed this was what was happening, but [it does not compile](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3YRqpR$12).

Comment: It cannot compile. `int` has no `push_back` method. Note OP claims the exact same expression works for `vector<int>`. Except it turns out OP is doing something *entirely different*....

Comment: @juanchopanza: I tried `vector<vector<int> >::push_back(int)` and it won't compile.

Comment: @nneonneo right, that constructor is explicit, so one needs `vector<vector<int> >::push_back(std::vector<int>(someInt))`

Comment: Well, it was compiled in C++98 mode. So I think the last sentence in your answer may not be correct.